# How to call the xarray's groupby function to group data by a combination of year and month

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

I have a DataArray object for a daily dataset that spans over a few years. This has one variable and three dimensions named `latitude`, `longitude` and `time` (daily). The time coordinates are like `time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2016-01-01 2016-01-02 ... 2018-12-31`

I would like to group the data by a combination of year and month by the DataArray's groupby function. But the following code only gives me the time coordinates in `int64`, saying 1, 2, 3, ..., 12.

```
da_groupby_monthly = da.groupby('time.month').sum('time')
print(da_groupby_monthly)
```

Output:

```
<xarray.DataArray (month: 12, latitude: 106, longitude: 193)>
dask.array<shape=(12, 106, 193), dtype=int32, chunksize=(1, 106, 193)>
Coordinates:
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 -39.2 -39.149525 ... -33.950478 -33.9
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 140.8 140.84792 140.89584 ... 149.95209 150.0
  * month      (month) int64 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

How to keep the data type of time `datetime64[ns]` and make the month coordinates to be something like "2016-01", "2016-02", "2016-03", ... ..., "2018-12", and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like using the resample method. Try this:

```
da_monthly  = da.resample('1m', on='time').sum()
```

Comment: Thanks @Dallas. I ran your code but received an error: `AttributeError: 'DataArray' object has no attribute 'index'`. I don't think index is an DataArray attribute.

Comment: Woops, sorry about that. Added it in at the last second. I edited it out. The resampling should work though.

Comment: Yes, this works. Now the time coordinate becomes `time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2017-01-31 2017-02-28 ... 2017-12-31`. Can you point me how to change the time index from yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy-mm for better representation?

Comment: ValueError: the first argument to .resample must be a dictionary.
Thus it should be: `da_monthly  = da.resample(time='1M').sum()`

Comment: Perhaps I am not understanding the question but I think you probably want to do the mean over the period, not the sum. `da_monthly  = da.resample(time='1M').mean()`

Answer (score 6):

To do an xarray groupby operation on multiple variables (e.g. year and month) more generally, you can combine variables in a pandas MultiIndex, make it a non-dimension coordinate, and pass it to groupby:

```
import pandas as pd
year_month_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([da['time.year'], da['time.month']])
da.coords['year_month'] = ('time', year_month_idx)
da_monthly = da.groupby('year_month').sum()
```

You can also create a MultiIndex for use with `groupby` by stacking coordinates. For example, given a set of latitude/longitude coordinates, you can groupby all unique lat-lon locations:

```
da_stacked = da.stack(latlon=['lat','lon'])
da_stacked.groupby('latlon').sum()
```